# Catch FTP Laravel exceptions

Tags: laravel, exception, ftp

I'm trying to work for the first time with Laravel exceptions handling.
What I need is to catch the different exceptions I get when trying to connect to FTP server (eg. cannot connect, wrong user/password, cannot find new files, cannot open files).
I'm stuck because I see that Laravel already has a class that throw Exceptions (located in vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapted/Ftp.php) and the Handler.php but I don't understand how they work together and how I can render different messages depending on Exception.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: use try catch to catch the specific exceptions then leftover catch it using `League\Flysystem\FilesystemException`

Answer (score 1):

The Handler.php will encapsule any call and handle any exception that extend the native class \Exception of PHP. So, no matter where the exception is triggered, the handler will try to handle it.

You can customize the response in two ways.

- Catch the exception before the handler:
  Basicly, surround the line of code that can trigger an exception with a try catch

```php
try {
    connectFTP();
} catch (\Exception $e) { //better use FilesystemException class in your case
    //handle it
}
```

- Adapt the Handler.php: Here there are two ways:

1. Patch : just intercept in the render method the exception in question

**Handler.php** laravel 8.x (add the method)

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instance of \FtpException) {
        //handle it here
    }
    parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

2. Use your own exception class:[More info here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#renderable-exceptions)

```
class FtpConnectionException extends Exception
{
    /**
     * Report the exception.
     *
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function report()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Render the exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request)
    {
        return response(...);
    }
}
```

How can you use your own exception class when the exception is triggered in the Vendor folder ? use the try catch method

```
try {
    connectFTP();
} catch (\Exception $e) { //better use FilesystemException class in your case
    throw new FtpConnectionException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e->getPrevious());
}
```

**NOTE**: Some exceptions dont reach the Handler.php like the CSRF 419 exception and the 404 page not found exception.

Comment: I've read also that you should say to the Handler that custom exceptions must be handled by my custom exception class. It is possible? Anyway, still trying your advices but doesn't get the expected result. Furthermore, I saw that Laravel 8 use Throwable instead of Exception class. Is there any difference? Sorry for all these questions.

Comment: @AlessandroBoscato check again the **2. Use Your own exception class**. Anyway, In PHP \Excetion::class extends \Throwable::class. Two classes extends \Throwable::class, Error::class and Exception::class. Error::class is used for more serious things like out of memory, Arithmetic error, compilation error...